# Qual o benefício e em que casos usar closures no PHP?

Tags: php, closures

Ex.: Por que utilizar uma closure para esta função:

Poderiamos fazer a mesma coisa sem uma closure, mas porque utilizar esta classe?

```
public function getTotal($tax)
{
    $total = 0.00;

    $callback =
        function ($quantity, $product) use ($tax, &$total)
        {
            $pricePerItem = constant(__CLASS__ . "::PRICE_" .
                strtoupper($product));
            $total += ($pricePerItem * $quantity) * ($tax + 1.0);
        };

    array_walk($this->products, $callback);
    return round($total, 2);
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Comment: Gosto muito de utilizar Closures no PHP 5.4, pois a mesma possui um método muito útil chamado bindTo()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Marcelo,

Na minha experiência com javascript e c# eu poderia dizer que Clousure é usado para explorar aspectos de escopo e contexto.

Em javascript e outras linguagens que permitam ser orientadas a eventos (como c#) a gente usa muito para acessar variáveis de outros escopos. É uma forma de você aplicar alguns design patterns como strategy e inversão de dependência.. a grosso modo falando: chamar uma função, dentro de outra função, que reaproveita valores da primeira função, num contexto reduzido...

Boa parte da galera não entende de programação orientadas a eventos e por isso reclamam injustamente de javascript.

No entanto, recomendo você dar uma lida aqui: http://howtonode.org/why-use-closure

Os exemplos são em javascript mas o conceito transcende linguagens.

Comment: Eu achava que era algo mais complexo, mas realmente ficou claro.

Comment: Eu uso muito! Fiquei muito feliz quando passei a conhecer o Action e Func do c# e vi que dava para manter o estilo de programação do javascript! Considerando que estilo em javascript depende da experiência de cada um...