# Variável definida, mas, mostra como indefinida

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```php
<?php

    // Lê conteúdo do txt
    $documento = 'TÍTULO I
    Dos Princípios Fundamentais

    Art. 1º A República Federativa do Brasil, formada pela união indissolúvel dos Estados e Municípios e do Distrito Federal, constitui-se em Estado Democrático de Direito e tem como fundamentos:

    I - a soberania;

    II - a cidadania

    III - a dignidade da pessoa humana;

    IV - os valores sociais do trabalho e da livre iniciativa;

    V - o pluralismo político.

    Parágrafo único. Todo o poder emana do povo, que o exerce por meio de representantes eleitos ou diretamente, nos termos desta Constituição.

    Art. 2º São Poderes da União, independentes e harmônicos entre si, o Legislativo, o Executivo e o Judiciário.

    Art. 3º Constituem objetivos fundamentais da República Federativa do Brasil:

    I - construir uma sociedade livre, justa e solidária;

    II - garantir o desenvolvimento nacional;

    III - erradicar a pobreza e a marginalização e reduzir as desigualdades sociais e regionais;

    IV - promover o bem de todos, sem preconceitos de origem, raça, sexo, cor, idade e quaisquer outras formas de discriminação.

    Art. 4º A República Federativa do Brasil rege-se nas suas relações internacionais pelos seguintes princípios:

    I - independência nacional;

    II - prevalência dos direitos humanos;

    III - autodeterminação dos povos;

    IV - não-intervenção;

    V - igualdade entre os Estados;

    VI - defesa da paz;

    VII - solução pacífica dos conflitos;

    VIII - repúdio ao terrorismo e ao racismo;

    IX - cooperação entre os povos para o progresso da humanidade;

    X - concessão de asilo político.

    Parágrafo único. A República Federativa do Brasil buscará a integração econômica, política, social e cultural dos povos da América Latina, visando à formação de uma comunidade latino-americana de nações.

    TÍTULO II
    Dos Direitos e Garantias Fundamentais
    CAPÍTULO I
    DOS DIREITOS E DEVERES INDIVIDUAIS E COLETIVOS

    Art. 5º Todos são iguais perante a lei, sem distinção de qualquer natureza, garantindo-se aos brasileiros e aos estrangeiros residentes no País a inviolabilidade do direito à vida, à liberdade, à igualdade, à segurança e à propriedade, nos termos seguintes:

    I - homens e mulheres são iguais em direitos e obrigações, nos termos desta Constituição;

    II - ninguém será obrigado a fazer ou deixar de fazer alguma coisa senão em virtude de lei;

    III - ninguém será submetido a tortura nem a tratamento desumano ou degradante;';


    function romano($romano) {
      switch (trim(strip_tags($romano))){
        case 'I':
          $romano = '1';
          break;
        case 'II':
          $romano = '2';
          break;
        case 'III':
          $romano = '3';
          break;  
        case 'IV':
          $romano = '4';
          break;
        case 'V':
          $romano = '5';
          break; 
        case 'VI':
          $romano = '6';
          break; 
        case 'VII':
          $romano = '7';
          break;
        case 'VIII':
          $romano = '8';
          break;
        case 'IX':
          $romano = '9';
          break;  
        case 'X':
          $romano = '10';
          break;   
        case 'XI':
          $romano = '11';
          break; 
        case 'XII':
          $romano = '12';
          break;     
        case 'XIII':
          $romano = '13';
          break;     
        case 'XIV':
          $romano = '14';
          break;  
        case 'XV':
          $romano = '15';
          break; 
        case 'XVI':
          $romano = '16';
          break; 
        case 'XVII':
          $romano = '17';
          break;     
        case 'XVIII':
          $romano = '18';
          break;     
        case 'XIX':
          $romano = '19';
          break;  
        case 'XX':
          $romano = '20';
          break;                                                
        case 'ÚNICO':
          $romano = '_unico';
          break;  
        case 'COMPLEMENTAR':
          $romano = '_complementar';
          break;
        case 'G':
          $romano = '_geral';
          break;  
        case 'E':
          $romano = '_especial';
          break;                                                                                                                                               
       default:
          $romano = '_especial';
      }
      return $romano;
    } 


    function concatena($concatenaHierarquia) {

        if ($contatenaParte = 1) {
          $concatenaHierarquia .= $valorParte;
        }
        if ($contatenaLivro = 1) {
          $concatenaHierarquia .= $valorLivro;
        }
        if ($contatenaTitulo = 1) {
          $concatenaHierarquia .= $valorTitulo;
        }
        if ($contatenaSubtitulo = 1) {
          $concatenaHierarquia .= $valorSubtitulo;
        }
        if ($contatenaCapitulo = 1) {
          $concatenaHierarquia .= $valorCapitulo;
        }
        if ($contatenaSecoes = 1) {
          $concatenaHierarquia .= $valorSecao;
        }
        if ($contatenaSubsecoes = 1) {
          $concatenaHierarquia .= $valorsubsecao;
        }
        if ($contatenaArtigos = 1) {
          $concatenaHierarquia .= $valorArtigo;
        }

        return $concatenaHierarquia;
    }

    // Variável das palavras chaves
    $encontraParte = "P A R T E";
    $encontraLivro = "LIVRO";
    $encontraTitulo = "TÍTULO";
    $encontraSubtitulo = "SUBTÍTULO";
    $encontraCapitulo = "CAPÍTULO";
    $encontraSecao = "Seção";
    $encontraSubsecao = "Subseção";
    $encontraArtigo = "Art.";
    $concatenaHierarquia = "";


    $valorParte = "";
    $valorLivro = "";
    $valorTitulo = "";
    $valorSubtitulo = "";
    $valorCapitulo = "";
    $valorSecao = "";
    $valorsubsecao = "";
    $valorArtigo = "";


    $documento = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $documento);
    // Converte em linhas
    $linhas = explode("\n", $documento);

    foreach ($linhas as $novalinha) {

      // Envolve cada linha em um parágrafo
      $novalinhas =   "<li><p>" . $novalinha . "</p></li>"; 

     // Verifica se tem o texto Linha na linha
     $procuraParte = strpos($novalinhas,$encontraParte);

     if ($procuraParte === false){
      $contatenaPars = 0;
     // Verifica se tem o texto Linha na linha
     $procuraLivro = strpos($novalinhas,$encontraLivro);

     if ($procuraLivro === false){
      $contatenaLivs = 0;
       // Verifica se tem o texto título na linha
       $procuraTitulo = strpos($novalinhas,$encontraTitulo);

       if ($procuraTitulo === false){
        $contatenaTits = 0;
         // Verifica se tem o texto Subtítulo na linha
         $procuraSubtitulo = strpos($novalinhas,$encontraSubtitulo);

         if ($procuraSubtitulo === false){
          $contatenaSubtits = 0;
            // Verifica se tem o texto capítulo na linha
            $procuraCapitulo = strpos($novalinhas,$encontraCapitulo);

            if ($procuraCapitulo === false){
            $contatenaCaps = 0;
             // Verifica se tem o texto Seção na linha
             $procuraSecao = strpos($novalinhas,$encontraSecao);
            
             if ($procuraSecao === false){
              $contatenaSecoes = 0;
                // Verifica se tem o texto Subseção na linha
                $procuraSubsecao = strpos($novalinhas,$encontraSubsecao);

                if ($procuraSubsecao === false){
                $contatenaSubsecoes = 0;
                   // Verifica se tem o texto Artigo na linha
                   $procuraArtigo = strpos($novalinhas,$encontraArtigo);

                   if ($procuraArtigo === false){
                    $contatenaArtigos = 0;
                      echo $novalinhas;      

                   } else {

                      $contatenaArtigos = 1;
                      // Captura o número do artigo para atribuir na ID                  
                      $artigo =  explode(" ", $novalinhas);

                      $caracteres = array("º",".");

                      $artigos = str_replace($caracteres, "", $artigo[1]);

                      $valorArtigo = 'artigo' . $artigos;

                      echo "</ul>";        
                      echo '<ul id="' . $valorArtigo . '" class="artigo">';                   
                      echo $novalinhas;

                      $valorArtigo = 'artigo' . $artigos;

                      echo "Concatena: " . concatena($concatenaHierarquia);                  
                   }     

                } else {

                  $contatenaSubsecao = 1;
                   // Captura o número romano da Subseção para atribuir na ID
                  $subsecao =  explode(" ", $novalinhas);
                  $caracteres = array("Subseção");
                  $subsecoes = romano($subsecao[1]);   
                  
                  $valorSubsecoes = 'subsecao' . $subsecoes;

                  echo "</ul>";        
                  echo '<ul id="' . $valorSubsecoes . '" class="subsecao">';                     
                  echo $novalinhas;  

                  echo "Concatena: " . concatena($concatenaHierarquia);                 
                }    

             } else {

                  $contatenaSecao = 1;
                   // Captura o número romano da Subseção para atribuir na ID
                  $secao =  explode(" ", $novalinhas);
                  $caracteres = array("Seção");
                  $secoes = romano($secao[1]);   

                  $valorSecoes = 'secao' . $secoes;

                  echo "</ul>";        
                  echo '<ul id="' . $valorSecoes . '" class="secao">';                      
                  echo $novalinhas;    

                  echo "Concatena: " . concatena($concatenaHierarquia);                  
             }     

          } else {

                  $contatenaCapitulo = 1;
                   // Captura o número romano da Subseção para atribuir na ID
                  $cap =  explode(" ", $novalinhas);
                  $caracteres = array("CAPÍTULO");
                  $caps = romano($cap[1]);  

                  $valorCapitulo = 'capitulo' . $caps;

                  echo "</ul>";        
                  echo '<ul id="' .  $valorCapitulo . '" class="capitulo">';                      
                  echo $novalinhas;  

                  echo "Concatena: " . concatena($concatenaHierarquia);                 
        }

       } else {

                  $contatenaSubtitulo = 1;
                  $subtit =  explode(" ", $novalinhas);
                  $caracteres = array("SUBTÍTULO");
                  $subtits = romano($subtit[1]);  

                  $valorSubtitulo = 'subtitulo' . $subtits;

                  echo "</ul>";        
                  echo '<ul id="' . $valorSubtitulo . '" class="subtitulo">';                      
                  echo $novalinhas; 

                  echo "Concatena: " . concatena($concatenaHierarquia);                 
       } 

     } else {

                  $contatenaTitulo = 1;
                  $tit =  explode(" ", $novalinhas);
                  $caracteres = array("TÍTULO");
                  $tits = romano($tit[1]);  

                  $valorTitulo = 'titulo' . $tits;

                  echo "</ul>";        
                  echo '<ul id="' . $valorTitulo  . '" class="titulo">';                      
                  echo $novalinhas; 

                  echo "Concatena: " . concatena($concatenaHierarquia);                            
       } 

     } else {

                  $contatenaLivro = 1;
                  $liv =  explode(" ", $novalinhas);
                  $caracteres = array("LIVRO");
                  $livs = romano($liv[1]);  

                  $valorLivro = 'livro' . $livs;

                  echo "</ul>";        
                  echo '<ul id="' . $valorLivro . '" class="livro">';                      
                  echo $novalinhas;

                  echo "Concatena: " . concatena($concatenaHierarquia);  
                  }
       } else {

                  $contatenaParte = 1;
                  $par =  explode(" ", $novalinhas);
                  $caracteres = array("PARTE");
                  $pars = romano($par[8]); 

                  $valorParte = 'parte' . $pars;

                  echo "</ul>";        
                  echo '<ul id="' . $valorParte. '" class="parte">';                      
                  echo $novalinhas;   

                  echo "Concatena: " . concatena($concatenaHierarquia);                                           
       }

    }

    ?>
```

Retorna este erro:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: valorParte in /home/5DUrnw/prog.php on line 155

Ele me diz que a variável não foi definida, mas na linha 194, eu a defini

Alguém sabe o porquê?

### [**`DEMO`**](http://ideone.com/RIV9LM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é o escopo das sua variáveis, elas devem ser passadas como argumento na sua função caso contario nada aconterá mesmo queo nome seja igual.

`$valorParte = "";` definida aqui não é a mesma encontrada na sua função(`$concatenaHierarquia .= $valorParte;`

Variáveis definidas no script são globais, as definidas em um função estão apenas disponiveis dentro dela.

A assinatura da função deve ficar assim:

```
function concatena($concatenaHierarquia, $valorParte,
    $valorLivro, $valorTitulo, $valorSubtitulo, $valorCapitulo,
    $valorSecao, $valorsubsecao, $valorArtigo) {
```

Comment: +1 e eu *acho* (não tenho certeza, pois não conheço PHP a fundo) que dá pra usar a função como se fosse um *closure* através de uma sintaxe própria ([fonte](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23943/qual-o-benef%C3%ADcio-e-em-que-casos-usar-closures-no-php)).

Comment: Vou estudar sobre o closure, mas, quanto a questão, eu estou definindo as variáveis fora da função, então elas deverias funcionar na função, não é isso?

Comment: @AlêMoraes, as variáveis definidas fora da função não são as mesmas utilizadas dentro de `concatena`.

Comment: Se utilizo a assinatura da função que você mostrou, tenho este erro > Warning: Missing argument 2 for concatena(), called in C:\wamp\www\leis\1 - converter_txt_ul\pesquisa_converter_txt_ul.php on line 300 and defined in C:\wamp\www\leis\1 - converter_txt_ul\pesquisa_converter_txt_ul.php on line 92

Comment: ele ainda não tem esse valorParte, né?

Comment: @AlêMoraes, vc deve chamar ela uma vez com todos os argumentos, so q parece isso não é mto adequado no seu caso, estou pensando em outra solução.

Comment: Valeu, o que eu pretendo é fazer a concatenação das hierarquias, não sei se a minha abordagem é boa

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando acessar de dentro de uma função mais interna as variáveis de uma função mais externa. Isso - quando suportado - se chama [***closure***](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31414/215), e embora em muitas linguagens toda função pode ser um *closure*, outras exigem uma sintaxe especial ou até não dão suporte a *closures* em absoluto.

Em PHP você pode transformar uma função "normal" em um *closure*, mas é necessário especificar exatamente quais variáveis da função externa você quer capturar:

```
$concatena = function ($concatenaHierarquia) use ($valorParte, $valorLivro,
                                                  $valorTitulo, $valorSubtitulo,
                                                  $valorCapitulo, $valorSecao,
                                                  $valorSubsecao, $valorArtigo) {

      if ($contatenaParte = 1) {
        $concatenaHierarquia .= $valorParte;
      }
      ...
};
```

<sub>[Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23943/215)</sub>

(Não esqueça o `;` no final, já que agora estamos atribuindo uma função a uma variável, não definindo uma função nomeada.)

Para chamá-la, é necessário agora usar o nome da variável:

```
                ...
                $valorArtigo = 'artigo' . $artigos;

                echo "Concatena: " . $concatena($concatenaHierarquia);                  
             }
```

[Exemplo no ideone](http://ideone.com/BjMvKE). Nota: não conferi a saída para ver se está tudo correto, pois o código postado é por demais extenso em relação ao que foi perguntado. Se houver mais erros ou outras dúvidas acerca do mesmo, sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta.